# Cucumber Ruby read Word Doc or Text

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm writing tests that will be confirming a lot of text on page.  It's for Terms and Conditions pages, Cookies, Privacy Policy etc.  Not what I'd like to do but it's a requirement I can't avoid.  I've heard that Cucumber can open a text file like. txt or .doc and compare the text on screen.

I've tried to find any reference to this but have come up short.  Is anyone able to point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Cucumber/aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba) has a Given step that goes like this :

```
Given a file named "foo" with:
"""
hello world
"""
```

You would then be able to check that you webpage has content with :

```
Then I should see "hello world"
```

And your step :

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" do |text
(page.should have_content(text))
```

Comment: Ye, I've used lots of those steps, but to confirm the amount of text sits within the terms and conditions etc, I was wondering if it's tidier to call the text from a text or Word file and compare text there

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about the amount of text present in the files. Tests are there to provide confidence above all else.

Answer (score 0):

I continued to play and found this works for a .txt file:

```
File.foreach(doc) do |line|
line = line.strip

within_window(->{ page.title == 'Cookies' }) do
  page_content = find('#main').text
  page_content.gsub!('‘',"'")
  page_content.gsub!('’',"'")

expect(page_content).to have_text line

    end
  end
end
```

doc is my filename variable.  I used `strip` to remove the newline characters created when pasting into the txt file. The cookies open up in a new tab so I navigated to that. I had invalid UTF-8 characters so just used `gsub` on those.

I'm sure there's a much better way to do this but this works for now

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [approval tests](http://approvaltests.com). A person approves the original, then the automated test verifies no change. If the license text changes, the test fails. If the text is supposed to pass, then the tester approves the new text, then it's automated thereafter.